# enum refuses to convert to String

Tags: c#, logging, enums, c#-3.0

A strange thing, I have two enum sets:

```
public enum ComponentActionTypes {
    Add = 0,
    Move = 1,
    Delete = 2,
    Edit = 3,
    Enable = 4,
    Disable = 5
}
public enum ComponentNames {
    Component = 0,
    Logo = 1,
    Main_menu = 2,
    Search_box = 3,
    Highlighter = 4,
    RSS = 5,
    Twitter = 6,
    YouTube = 7
}
```

when I try to print the following text,

```
ActionText =
string.Format("{0}ed a {1}", action.ComponentActionType, action.ComponentName);
```

will generate:

`184ed a Logo` instead of `Added a Logo`

`action.ComponentActionType` is converted to number (`ToString` didn't help) and also a

strange number (like `184`, not the enum number itself)

Any idea how to solve this?

**Update:**

```
namespace BrandToolbar.Common.ActionLog.Model
{
    public class ActionItem
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public Int64 PublicId { get; set; }
        public ComponentActionTypes ComponentActionType { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public ComponentNames ComponentName { get; set; }
        public string UiJsonPreview { get; set; }
    }
}


public static ActionItemUI ConvertModelToUiObj(ActionItem action)
{
    return new ActionItemUI()
    {
        ActionText = string.Format(
            "{0}ed a {1}",
            action.ComponentActionType,
            action.ComponentName
        ).Replace("_", " "),
        TooltipText = string.Format(
            "{0}ed on {1}",
            action.ComponentActionType,
            action.Date.ToString(StringFormatter.DateFormat)
        ),
        ImageUrl = string.Empty,
        ConponentText = string.Empty
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `action.ComponentActionType` is really of type `ComponentActionTypes`?

Comment: Might be a lame question, but are you sure **action.ComponentActionType** is of type ComponentActionTypes? I would think that .ToString() would in the least give you what you need

Comment: Can you show the code that creates your action object?  Also, the Action class might be useful to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check how the ComponentActionType field is filled? Enum values can contain other values than listed. For example: this is perfectly valid:

```
    enum foo {A = 1,B = 2,C = 3};
    var b = (foo)7;
```

(If it wasn't allowed by default, masking with enums would not be possible). The string representation in this case for b is 7, because it cannot be matched to an item in the enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

`ComponentActionTypes.Add` has value == 0. `action.ComponentActionType` from code sample has value == 184. So far as enum variables allow to store values, which are not in enum definition, you've got such result.

You need to check, why `action.ComponentActionType` equals to 184.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(ComponentActionTypes), action.ComponentAction);
```

Not sure about the "184" through.